# How can I convert rich text to plain text in advanced scripting?

Tags: naturallyspeaking

I would like to write a voice command to paste the clipboard in plain text. How can I convert rich text to plain text in advanced scripting?

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any solution using advanced scripting.

As a pis-aller, I have set up a shortcut that copies content to the clipboard using [PureText 3.0](http://stevemiller.net/puretext/):

[image]

[image: enter image here]

[image]

The following [AHK script](https://superuser.com/a/153846/116475) should also work, but might be unfriendly with  Unicode characters:

```
^!v::
   ClipboardTemp = %ClipBoardAll%
   ClipBoard = %ClipBoard%
   Send ^v
   sleep, 30
   ClipBoard = %ClipboardTemp%
Return
```